# Sample ASP.NET application for absolute beginners

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, sample

One friend of mine is beginner programmer and he is trying to learn <strike>classic</strike> ASP.NET. I want to recommend him some small open source application to study. I don't want to confuse him with advanced topics or mislead him with wild approaches. What application should I recommend to him?

---

Edit: I clearly failed to ask this question. I am not looking for beginner tutorial or set of examples. I am looking for real life application which helps him make better pictures how all samples he already look at works together.

Comment: Careful with the word "Classic" around asp.net! We wouldn't want anyone to get the wrong idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ASP .NET Open Source projects.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/open-source